# Network service that is both connected and connectionless

Tags: layer3

I'm reading through Kuross *"Computer Networking, a Top Down Approach"*.  In the chapter about the network layer, they mention

> "In all major computer network architectures to date (Internet, ATM, frame relay, and so on), the network layer provides either a host-to-host connectionless serv- ice or a host-to-host connection service, but not both. Computer networks that provide only a connection service at the network layer are called virtual-circuit (VC) networks; computer networks that provide only a connectionless service at the network layer are called datagram networks."

I'm having trouble understanding **why** this is, and also am curious if there are any examples of network architectures which offer both a h2h connected and and h2h connectionless service, since the the author mentions only *major computer network architectures* being one or the other.  Should he have instead said ***all** computer network architectures*.

Comment: Without proper context this is probably not possible to answer. Does the author mean connect{ed/ionless} protocols running _on top of_ the network layer or _at_ the network layer itself? (as in "IP is basically connectionless while ATM uses a virtual circuit")

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  *At* the layer was what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the network layer, whether the data transport is essentially connection-based or connection-less is a question of routing paradigm.

In a connection-based network, the route from source to destination is set up and fixed when the connection is established. Usually, bandwidth is reserved. Once the data flow starts, it is extremely deterministic. Data may be passed as a continuous stream or in packets. Think of the old telephone system or the more modern ATM.

In a connection-less network, data is always passed in packets. Each packet is routed on its own, goes from hop to hop and different packets may find different paths. Bandwidth availability may change during the connection, delayed packets are possible, overloaded hops may lose packets.

In a nutshell, this is an architectural decision. You can't do both at the same time or even make it user-selectable. On a higher layer, you can create a connection-less protocol in a connection-based network (e.g. pass IP over ATM) and vice versa (TCP over IP), but you can't change the underlying, basic character.

Connection-based networks are easier to build and they're deterministic by design - but they waste bandwidth and the routing nodes are more complex (they need to know about the open connections and routes).

Connection-less networks may be harder to control and they are not very deterministic. However, they are very bandwidth-efficient and the routers can be fairly simple (stateless).

Answer (score 2):

In this book 6th edition, this sentence is in section 4.2, page 313

The complete preamble of this chapter is as follow:

> **4.2 Virtual Circuit and Datagram Networks**
>
> Recall from Chapter 3 that a transport layer can offer applications
>   connectionless service or connection-oriented service between two
>   processes. For example, the Inter- net’s transport layer provides each
>   application a choice between two services: UDP, a connectionless
>   service; or TCP, a connection-oriented service. In a similar manner, a
>   network layer can provide connectionless service or connection service
>   between two hosts. Network-layer connection and connectionless
>   services in many ways parallel transport-layer connection-oriented and
>   connectionless services. For example, a net- work-layer connection
>   service begins with handshaking between the source and desti- nation
>   hosts; and a network-layer connectionless service does not have any
>   handshaking preliminaries.
>   Although the network-layer connection and
>   connectionless services have some parallels with transport-layer
>   connection-oriented and connectionless services, there are crucial
>   differences:
>
> - In the network layer, these services are host-to-host
>     services provided by the net- work layer for the transport layer. In
>     the transport layer these services are process- to-process services
>     provided by the transport layer for the application layer.
> - In all major computer network architectures to date (Internet, ATM, frame
>     relay, and so on), the network layer provides either a host-to-host
>     connectionless serv- ice or a host-to-host connection service, but not
>     both. Computer networks that provide only a connection service at the
>     network layer are called virtual-circuit (VC) networks; computer
>     networks that provide only a connectionless service at the network
>     layer are called datagram networks.
> - The implementations of
>     connection-oriented service in the transport layer and the connection
>     service in the network layer are fundamentally different. We saw in
>     the previous chapter that the transport-layer connection-oriented
>     service is 314 CHAPTER 4 • THE NETWORK LAYER implemented at the edge
>     of the network in the end systems; we’ll see shortly that the
>     network-layer connection service is implemented in the routers in the
>     net- work core as well as in the end systems.
>
> Virtual-circuit and
>   datagram networks are two fundamental classes of computer net- works.
>   They use very different information in making their forwarding
>   decisions. Let’s now take a closer look at their implementations.

So it clear that we are not talking about TCP / UDP here.

This is further explain the remaining of this chapter, but the author actually speak here about two different kinds of network architecture.

As such a network can only be of one type, and not both

The examples given by the author are `ATM` and `Frame Relay`for Virtual Circuits Networks (i.e. connection oriented) and the Internet for Datagram Network (i.e. connection-less)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT.

I missed the layer 3 portion in the original question so I just wanted to change my answer. It was originally based on layer 4 only... Apologies.

IP (Internet Protocol) is a layer 3 connection (reliable) oriented protocol. It's used for many of today's networks. TCP is the layer 4 (transport layer) it works as a connection oriented (reliable) communication. I only mention it as a revenge to the comparison below with TP4.

CLNS (Connectionless Network Service) is an example of a connectionless (best-effort) layer 3 protocol. It does not require a "circuit" be established before transmitting data. One example of its use is the Telecom industry around the world. CLNS uses TP4 at layer 4 (transport layer). It is similar to TCP for IP.

I realize TCP and TP4 are not layer three but added them for comparison of the example.

There are others but that's one example.

Comment: Neither TCP nor UDP are network layer protocols.

Comment: You are correct, I missed that and have edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are particularly talking about the circuit switching and packet switching. Circuit switching is connection oriented where the connection is made before forwarding the traffic and connection less is the packet switching. 
If it is right then it depends upon the service which is under consideration. Connection oriented is basically used for the services which requires the reliability, less RTT for example the voice service in CDMA (3G) or GSM (2G). In connection oriented the first connection is made before sending the actual traffic and for PS the packets flow through the random paths before reaching the final destination and the final destination will reassemble it. Here is one issue it is possible some of the packets reach slow and the TCP transmit timer has been triggered. This will lead two major network KPI degradation which is TCP re-transmission and Out of order packets. In connection oriented there is a dedicated path and certain performance parameters are guaranteed.

I hope I answered your question if not please mention the snapshots of your contents which are you currently reading. If I hit the right target to what you are actually looking for then Read SS7 Signalling. Search on the internet.

Comment: Connection-oriented doesn't necessarily mean circuit switched - ATM is packet based and switches packets but is connection-oriented through virtual circuits.